# How to create and use filters on search result page in laravel?

Tags: laravel, filter, pagination, laravel-5.5

I have two page(views). Search Form view and Search Result View.
Search Result page has multiple filters to refine the search result.

[Find the Search Form here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwY2U.png)

[Find the Filters here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsrhD.png)

How to create and use filters to refine results on the search result page?

Comment: Add codes what you have done till now

Comment: I have done code of search result. that is working fine but no idea how to implement filters.